# Crystal Reports is showing just one record

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, crystal-reports

I'm a noob in Crystal Reports. I have a DataTable getting information from a DataGridView, here's the code:

```
 Dim dt As New DataTable
        With dt
            .Columns.Add("ID")
            .Columns.Add("Nombre")
            .Columns.Add("Cantidad")
            .Columns.Add("Descripcion")
            .Columns.Add("Fecha")
            .Columns.Add("Modulo")

        End With
        Dim rptDoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
        rptDoc = New mello
        For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In dgvDatos.Rows
            dt.Rows.Add(dr.Cells(0).Value, dr.Cells(1).Value, dr.Cells(2).Value, dr.Cells(3).Value, dr.Cells(4).Value, dr.Cells(5).Value)
            rptDoc.SetDataSource(dt)
            Crystalino.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc
        Next
        '
        Crystalino.ShowDialog()
        Crystalino.Dispose()
```

But when I Run the program, it shows just one record:

[image]

So, I'd apreciate if you guys could help me

Comment: Firstly, what type of object is `mello`? Secondly, take the line `Crystalino.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc` out and put it after `Next`

Comment: 'mello' is a Crystal Report. Thanks.

Comment: Did that fix the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Did you put your row data in the details Section in the report designer ?

If you put your data in an other section it will only display the first result and not fetch all the data. You 'll need to put your data in the details section to make crystalreport fetch your data ( row's data in your case )